# how can I pass default information like loginUserInfo to MyScheduler in spring?

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I am using annotation based scheduler like  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1200000)
and I want to pass information like langId , loginUserId etc.

I have a scheduler MyScheduler, I have configured it in .property file as:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
 <bean id="myScheduler" class="ab.abc.txn.service.MyScheduler"></bean>
```

Comment: Since there is no connection between a scheduled task and one (of possibly many) logged in users i can't see how this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

use `<property` in bean defination

Comment: I didnt get it. can u please eloberate. One thing I want to add is This info which I am passing can be changed for example if one use is loggin in with english langId passed would be 1 if its spanish it would be 2

Comment: <bean ..> <property name="name" value="#{ obj.val}" > </bean> use SpEL